# How do I create a Nav bar using buttons or how can I change the font size of the text in my nav bar

Tags: html, css

I have a nav bar im making and I want to be able to either put the text in actual buttons or just increase the font size as it is now, i have tried to define it like this..

```
navbar {
  font-size: 20px;
}

<nav class="navbar">
<a href="link">Prezi</a>
</nav>
```

but it's not working for me and i don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.

```css
.navbar {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.navbar a {
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.navbar a:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
    <a href="link">Prezi</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: ok sweet it worked! is there a way to put buttons in my navbar without using the <button> element?

Comment: Do you want use only a tag?

Comment: is there a way you can message me on stackoverflow? it might be easier than cluttering this post with stuff that doesn't pertain to the original question

Comment: I will upvote you and then you can participate chat rooms in chat stack overflow. I will create a room so that you can talk to me.

Comment: ok sweet, let me know how to get to the room once u create it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227550/discussion-between-jeremy-and-george).

Comment: @Jeremy, I sent you a message in there.

Answer (score 1):

To style a class you will have to put a dot in front of the name in your css file so instead of `navbar` you will get `.navbar`. For id's you have to put a `#` in front of it. The way you try to adress it now is as a default html tag. The tag is not navbar but nav so to let it work like you have now you have to change `navbar {}` to `nav {}`